# Is there a way to change the color of the text inside a textfield as you are typing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am looking to change the colour of the font if the text length of the textfield is less than 4. But I only want it to show up when I have finished typing (Gone off the text field).

I have this

```
if ([_username.text length] < 4){
    _username.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else{
    _username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

But I don't know what I have to "put it inside of" (New to objective C - Don't know the lingo).

I have tried this but it doesn't work properly as when you return to the text field the font stays red. I want it so that when you are typing it is allways black. And also it only becomes red if you hit the return (Next) key.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

---

## Also why is this not working?

```
if (textField == _confirm) {
        int resultantLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;
        
        NSLog(@"Length After Additions And Subtractions Will Be: %i letters", resultantLength);
        
        if (![_confirm.text isEqualToString:_password.text]) {
            textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [_next setEnabled:NO];

        }else{
            [_next setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to wait til the user is done add this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField.text.length < 4){
        textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else{
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

If you'd like to do it in real time:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    int resultantLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;

    NSLog(@"Length After Additions And Subtractions Will Be: %i letters", resultantLength);

    if (resultantLength < 4){
        textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else{
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Note that this will affect any textField that uses the same delegate.  If you'd like to only respond to a specific textField, for example `_username`, do this:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField == _username) {
        int resultantLength = textField.text.length + string.length - range.length;

        NSLog(@"Length After Additions And Subtractions Will Be: %i letters", resultantLength);

        if (resultantLength < 4){
            textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        else{
            textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Make sure your ViewController is set up for UITextFieldDelegate protocol and it is the delegate of your textField

Comment: Please reread the question. The OP wants to change the color after the user leaves the text field, not as it is changed.

Comment: @Logan I have found an issue with this. If you type first off say "hello" all the way up to "hell" is red and then when you add the "o" it is black - fine. But then if you take away the "o" it is still black. It should go back to red?

Comment: @Maximilian - I just noticed that and fixed it.

Comment: @Logan Though having said that, I think showing it realtime is probably a better UX.

Comment: I have found a new problem that is my fault. I forgot to tell you that I also have two other text fields. Which seem to alter the color of the first when edited.

Comment: `- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    
    int resultantLength = _username.text.length + string.length - range.length;
    
    NSLog(@"Length After Additions And Subtractions Will Be: %i letters", resultantLength);
    
    if (resultantLength < 4){
        _username.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else{
        _username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    
    return YES;
}`

Comment: @Maximilian - In general, please refrain from adding code as a comment.  Update your answer and notify via comment.  Copy my code exactly, using the `textField` variable as opposed to `_username` if you set `_username` no matter which textField is editing will change the `_username` textfield.  Do you want it to affect ONLY the `_username` textfield?

Comment: @Maximilian - I updated my answer for what I am pretty sure you are trying to do.

Comment: @Logan sorry to bother you! Why does [see updated question] not work also?

Comment: _next is a button. It disables it.

Answer (score 1):

To change the text color on every key press, do this:

```
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

//....

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length > 4) {
      //change color
    } else {
       //change to another color
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply use the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NSAttributedString`.
Scan through the word and find the range of your character or letter and change its color.

```
- (IBAction)colorWord:(id)sender {
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text.text];

NSArray *words=[self.text.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *word in words) {        
    if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        NSRange range=[self.text.text rangeOfString:word];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];           
    }
}
[self.text setAttributedText:string];
```

}

The code above will work for changing the color of a specific word in a sentence. I'm sure you can do the same for a character in a word.

Good luck!

ERID: Here's where I got the code snip-it from. There's also a working app, so you can have a look.
[AttributedStringOneWord](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5453557/attributedstringoneword-40k?da=y)

Comment: This is not what the OP needs. Simply setting the text field's `textColor` is all that is needed.

Comment: Hm, yeah sorry, I was under the impression he wanted to change the color of EACH character. Not the entire word. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods:

1. `-textFieldDidEndEditing:`

   - to set red color if needed
2. `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`

   - to reset to black color (incase the text was red and you came back to edit)

Example:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //to set font color to black when user begins editing the textField
    [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //for implementing the red font color logic
    NSString *strCurrent = textField.text;

    if (strCurrent.length < 4) {
        [textField setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    } else {
        [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

---

*Since you're new...*
**Note:**

1. Set delegate for the `textField` object

   - `[textFieldObject setDelegate:self];`
2. In the .h of your class file, declare the protocol `<UITextFieldDelegate>`

   - example: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`